# Django ModelForm filtrar segun otro campo

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

Estoy intentando hacer que la lista desplegable de un campo cambie segun lo que hayan seleccionado en otro campo, en mi caso que cambie el estado segun el municipio seleccionado, es decir que solo salgan los estados que corresponden a ese municipio

Models.py

```
class Temporal(models.Model):
    a000sap = models.CharField(max_length=25)
    codigo_unico = models.CharField(max_length=25)
    visitas = models.IntegerField()
    latitud = models.FloatField()
    longitud = models.FloatField()
    direccion_fisica = models.CharField(max_length=2000)
    direccion_fiscal = models.CharField(max_length=2000)
    persona_contacto = models.CharField(max_length=70)
    municipio_key = models.ForeignKey(Municipios, 
    on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True)
    estado_key =models.ForeignKey(Estados,on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True)


class Ciudades(models.Model):
    id_ciudad = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    id_estado = models.ForeignKey(Estados, db_column='id_estado')
    ciudad = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    capital = models.SmallIntegerField()
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.ciudad, self.capital)

class Municipios(models.Model):
    id_municipio = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    id_estado = models.ForeignKey(Estados, db_column='id_estado')
    municipio = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.municipio
```

Forms.py

```
class editar(ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(editar, self).__init__(*args,**kwargs)
        self.fields['estado'].queryset = Municipios.objects.filter(municipio__iexact=(VARIABLE CON MUNICIPIO QUE ELIGIO EL USER)
        for f in self.fields.items():
            if (f[0] in meses) or (f[0] == 'punto_rojo'):
                continue
            else:
                self.fields[f[0]].widget.attrs["class"] = 'form-control'
        self.fields['codigo_unico'].widget.attrs["readonly"] = True
    class Meta:
        model = Temporal
        fields = '__all__'
```

No se como obtener el valor del campo municipio para insertarlo en el queryset

Comment: Verifique si [este enlace](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37576225/8933039) le da una idea para resolver su problema.

Answer (score 0):

De algún modo tienes que recoger los datos para poder procesar en la vista la información, lo ideal es pasarlo por medio de "get" por ejemplo:

```
class Editar(forms.ModelForm):
    model = Temporal
    fields = '__all__'

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        state = kwargs.pop('departament')
        super(editar, self).__init__(*args,**kwargs)
        cities_by_state = Municipios.objects.filter(municipio__iexact=state)
        self.fields['estado'].queryset =cities_by_state
        for f in self.fields.items():
            if (f[0] in meses) or (f[0] == 'punto_rojo'):
                continue
            else:
                self.fields[f[0]].widget.attrs["class"] = 'form-control'
        self.fields['codigo_unico'].widget.attrs["readonly"] = True


class EditarFormView(FormView):

    def get_form_kwargs(self):
        kwargs = super().get_form_kwargs()
        kwargs['state'] = self.request.GET.get('state')
        return kwargs
```